# AWS Windows AMI versions depricated

Tags: amazon-ami

In April this year, I wrote some code to launch EC2 Windows instances using this public AMI

```
region: us-east-1
id:     ami-ee8dbb88
name:   amazon/Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-Base-2017.03.15
```

(I'm using `us-east-1` region as an example, but we actually want to cover several regions):

I chose this AMI because, at the time, it appeared as one of the defaults in the [EC2 launch wizard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#LaunchInstanceWizard)

Now my code fails, because that AMI doesn't exist. I have just searched for  more recent versions and updated the code, but I want to avoid this problem next time.

My questions are:

- Is there some concept of an official 'current' version of Windows AMIs, and a reliable way to programmatically query that?
- Is this the wrong approach? Should we just maintain our own clones of these AMIs if we want good availability?

Comment: You might be able to work something out using the API. [Docs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/finding-an-ami.html#finding-an-ami-aws-cli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a supported way to find current Windows AMIs, described in this blog post:

[Query for the Latest Windows AMI Using Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/query-for-the-latest-windows-ami-using-systems-manager-parameter-store/)